# Prove that this is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P^4$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree <4. Consider the following mapping : $F: P^4 \to P^4 $
 $f(x) \to xf'(x) + f(x)$

Prove that this is a linear transformation:

My attempt: $f(x+y)=xf'(x+y) + yf'(x+y) + f(x+y)$ But now I'm a bit stuck, because if we substitute f(x+y) in the image, we have to do it again and again. Also, I don't see what I can do with the two $f'(x+y)$, how can I deal with them ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: $Ff(x)=xf'(x)+f(x)$ check $F(kf+g)=kFf+Fg$

Comment: But that's what I've done ??

Comment: no it is not, $F$ is mapping, $f$, $g$ are elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a ( common ) mistake. The application you consider is $F : P^4 \rightarrow P^4$, $f \mapsto F\left(f\right)$ and you in your case have considered the function $x \mapsto F\left(f\right)\left(x\right)$.

Here for two polynomials $f$ and $g$ in $P^4$ and a scalar $\lambda$
$$
F\left(\lambda f + g\right)(x)=x\left(\lambda f + g\right)'\left(x\right)+\left(\lambda f + g\right)\left(x\right)=x\left(\lambda f'\left(x\right)+g'\left(x\right)\right)+\left(\lambda f(x) + g(x)\right)
$$